# Gale Shapley Preferences generation

Tags: c++

I have a c++ code I am working on that is stumping me. I have written a Gale Shapley algorithm. I am now trying to create a function that generates all possible groups of preferences. I'll try to makes this as clear as possible.

Say I have 3 men and 3 woman.

Each man or woman would have a preference list of 3 men or 3 woman.

For each person there can be 6 different list.

So there can be 6*5*4 = 120 different groups of 3 to test for a group of men or women. Now since there is 3 men and 3 women there are 120^2 total different groupings to test. I need to generate all 14440 of these options so I can pass these into my algorithm to test if I can break it.

I have been trying for days to figure out how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Nested loops should do it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like you need to figure out all the possible permutations of preference lists that each man and woman can have. [`std::next_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) inside nested loops seems like a good way to handle this.

Something like:

```
// initialize men's preferences
std::vector<int> menPreferences(numMen*numWomen); 
for (int i = 0; i < numMen; ++i) {
    resetPermutation(menPreferences, i, numWomen);
}

// intialize women's preferences
std::vector<int> womenPreferences(numWomen*numMen);
for (int j = 0; j < numWomen; ++j) {
    resetPermutation(womenPreferences, j, numMen);
}

// note that each individual preference list is currently sorted (pre-req of std::next_permutation)
// nested loops to consider all the possible permutations

// First handle men
for (int i = 0; i < numMen; ++i) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator manIt = menPreferences.begin() + (i*numWomen);
    do {

        // Now handle women
        for (int j = 0; j < numWomen; ++j) {
            std::vector<int>::iterator womanIt = womenPreferences.begin() + (j*numMen);
            do {

                // Actually test algorithm with current preference lists
                testGaleShapely(menPreferences, womenPreferences);

            } while ( std::next_permutation(womanIt, womanIt+numMen) );

            // Reset permutation for next iteration
            resetPermutation(womenPreferences, j, numMen);
        }
    } while ( std::next_permutation(manIt, manIt+numWomen) );

    // Reset permutation for next iteration
    resetPermutation(menPreferences, i, numWomen);
}
```

And then the simple `resetPermutation` function would be defined as:

```
// Reset the permutation for an individual's preference list 
void resetPermutation(std::vector<int>& preferences, int index, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        preferences[index*size + i] = i;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I have written this up on the fly and tested none of it. It most certainly has errors in it (which anyone is free to let me know about, so I can fix). However, I hope it gives you a good idea for how to handle this problem.